# using HAProxy to expose service UI - behind haproxy on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, https, url-routing, haproxy, prefect

**My problem:**
Exposing a UI for service behind haproxy fails

**Details:**
I'm using a server ([Prefect](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect-helm/tree/main/charts/prefect-server)) that exposes an API and UI in different urls.
Using haproxy for routing and authentication with the API works as expected.
But, When accessing the UI with a browser the first request succeeds and returns an html file, and subsequent requests for assets are going to a different address and it messes up the routing.

haproxy settings i'm using right now:

```
acl SERVER path_reg -i /SERVER/
use_backend SERVER if SERVER

backend SERVER
        http-request replace-path /SERVER(.*) \1
        server-template web 50 prefect-server.default.svc.cluster.local:4200 check resolvers mydns init-addr none
```

current URL of accessing the service UI:
https://<cluster public address>/SERVER/dashboard

in chrome I see these failed https calls:
[chrome failed calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Gq6.png)

meaning that in the routing somewhere the "SERVER" part is dropped from the URL and requests look like this:
https://<cluster public address>/<some asset inside server>